# Can I set multiple properties on a template at the same time with one parameter?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Frame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
       x:Class="Japanese.Templates.ButtonTemplate" 
       x:Name="this" CornerRadius="5" 
       BackgroundColor="{Binding FrameBackgroundColor, Source={x:Reference this}}"
       BorderColor="{Binding FrameBorderColor, Source={x:Reference this}}"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasShadow="false" 
       HeightRequest="35" Padding="0">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="{Binding Text,  Source={x:Reference this}}" FontSize="16" 
               TextColor="{Binding LabelTextColor, Source={x:Reference this}}"
               x:Name="label1"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapButtonPressed, Source={x:Reference this}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Param, Source={x:Reference this}}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

and this backing CS:

```
public partial class ButtonTemplate : Frame
{
    public event EventHandler Action;

    public ButtonTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ICommand TapButtonPressed
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((object componentIdentifier) =>
            {
                this.Action?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            });
         }
     }

     public static readonly BindableProperty EnabledProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(Enabled),
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(ButtonTemplate),
                default(bool));
                        
     public bool Enabled { get; set; }

     public static readonly BindableProperty FrameBackgroundColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(FrameBackgroundColor),
                typeof(Color),
                typeof(ButtonTemplate),
                default(Color));
        
     public static readonly BindableProperty FrameBorderColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(FrameBorderColor),
                typeof(Color),
                typeof(ButtonTemplate),
                default(Color));
        
     public static readonly BindableProperty ParamProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(Param),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(ButtonTemplate),
                default(string));
        
     public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTextColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(LabelTextColor),
                typeof(Color),
                typeof(ButtonTemplate),
                default(Color));
        
     public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(Text),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(ButtonTemplate),
                default(string));
        
     public Color FrameBackgroundColor
     {
         get { return (Color)GetValue(FrameBackgroundColorProperty); }
         set { SetValue(FrameBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
     }

     public Color FrameBorderColor
     {
         get { return (Color)GetValue(FrameBorderColorProperty); }
         set { SetValue(FrameBorderColorProperty, value); }
     }

     public Color LabelTextColor
     {
         get { return (Color)GetValue(LabelTextColorProperty); }
         set { SetValue(LabelTextColorProperty, value); }
     }

     public string Param
     {
         get { return (string)GetValue(ParamProperty); }
         set { SetValue(ParamProperty, value); }
     }

     public string Text
     {
         get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
         set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
     }
 }
```

Currently I use bindings to set TextColor, BorderColor and BackgroundColor. But all I need is two states enabled and disabled.  Is there a way I can set the three binding values all at the same time to one or other color set with just one binding parameter?

**Edit:**

So what I need is to just have one parameter so for example:

```
<template:button enabled="true">
```

BackgroundColor will be Blue

BorderColor will be Gray

TextColor will be White

Or:

```
<template:button enabled="false">
```

BackgroundColor will be White

BorderColor will be Black

TextColor will be Gray

Answer (score 3):

So basically, you are trying to create a reusable control.

The easiest thing to do is just add an `Enabled` property on this in the code-behind. This also allows you to set it from XAML.

Just add: `public bool Enabled { get; set; }`.

You could then in the setter, reference the controls in your template by a name and set the properties like that. You would have to add an `x:Key` attribute to each of the controls.

Seeing you already have data-binding in place, you should be able to just update the properties that you are binding to from the setter.

If you also want to be able to bind to the new `Enabled` property, you will have to create it as a `BindableProperty` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)). Add this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty EnabledProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create (nameof(Enabled), typeof(bool), typeof(ButtonTemplate), null, propertyChanged: OnEnabledChanged);

public bool Enabled { get; set; }

private static void OnEnabledChanged (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
  // Set the color properties here
}
```

The `BindableProperty` has an on property changed method where you can set the properties for the colors. By implementing it like this, you can also bind to the `Enabled` property: `<template:button enabled="{Binding IsValid}">`

*Edit:*

What I mean by setting the properties is this. But from your new code, I see you don't have data-binding in place here. You do have named your controls, so you can just refer to them and set their properties like this:

```
private static void OnEnabledChanged (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    // Referencing controls
    if ((bool)newValue)
    {
        BorderColor = Color.Red;
        label1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        BorderColor = Color.Green;
        label1.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
    }

    // Using bindings
    if ((bool)newValue)
    {
        FrameBackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        FrameBorderColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        FrameBackgroundColor = Color.Green;
        FrameBorderColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

I see that you have named your `Frame` `this`. That could cause problems since `this` is a reserved keyword in .NET. You might want to change that.

Comment: Sorry but I think my question was not clear as your answer doesn’t help me. I added something to the question.  Can you have a look.  Thanks

Comment: Updated to your "new" question :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Just one last question.  I have been using this:         public bool Enabled
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(EnabledProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EnabledProperty, value); }
        }    But you don't use that in your answer.  Is your answer and the way I did it the same?

Comment: Also can you give me an example of how I could set multiple color properties in the OnEnabledChanged.  Thanks

Comment: Yes with the `SetValue` etc. the `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be used as well, causing the UI to updated automatically, so dont worry about that. You can just set the properties like you would do normally in that method.

Comment: I'm sorry Gerald but I really don't understand what you are trying to say with your answer.  It's too complicated for me.  I added in the backing CS to my question.  For your answer could you use my code and add in what you think is needed so that it's a bit clearer and easier to follow. Thank you

Comment: The color properties that you have implemented are not needed. If I understand correctly, you want to set the color depending on the `Enabled` property. If you still want to make the colors dynamic, you would have to create properties for both: `FrameBorderColorEnabled` and `FrameBorderColorDisabled` for instance. In any case, I have updated my answer a little bit, I hope it makes sense. Also, the answer about the VisualStateManager below is also a good one.

Comment: Thanks Gerald but I do have data binding on the colors FrameBorderColor, FrameBackgroundColor and LabelTextColor. Rather than refer to the controls by name can I use those bindings to change the color?

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend using [`VisualStateManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager) for this particular use-case.

**For e.g.**

```
<Frame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SampleApp.ButtonView"
             x:Name="this"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             CornerRadius="5"
             HasShadow="false" 
             HeightRequest="35" Padding="0">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Gray" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Black" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}"
               IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Source={x:Reference this}}"
               FontSize="16" 
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Gray" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Label>
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapButtonPressed,Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding Param, Source={x:Reference this}}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class ButtonView : Frame
{
    public ButtonView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal");
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

}
```